# set whenever gem pointing to the application time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am trying to use `whenever gem` and what I am trying to do is I want `whenever gem` takes config time.

**application.rb**

```
config.time_zone = 'Sydney'
```

**schedule.rb**

```
every :sunday, at: '12am' do
  runner "User.warning"
end
```

so I want to run `User.warning` every sunday at 12am in **Sydney** time. Any help to set `whenever gem` to point to config time?

Answer (score 0):

The `whenever gem` is to write crontabs with the ruby syntax. The crontabs are running on the machine, so I think your best chance is to set the system time where the application is running on to **Sydney** timezone.